# FCKEditor 2.6x seems to cut off at the bottom in Chrome

Tags: google-chrome, border, fckeditor

The bottom of the FCKEditor seems to cut off - the border is not seen.  This only happens in Google Chrome. IE and Firefox seem to be ok.  This is the FCKEditor control with barely any  customization.

[image]

Is there anyway to fix this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Appears to be a known bug in FCKEditor 2.6.5.  Dravis in the CKEditor forums has posted a patch to fix the height calculation here:

http://cksource.com/forums/viewtopic.php?p=41296#p41296

(Copied from link, in case the forums are down):

> In fckeditor.html, I changed line 286 from this:
>
> ```
> eInnerElement.style.height = ( oCell.scrollHeight - 2 ) + 'px' ;
> ```
>
> To this:
>
> ```
> if ( FCKBrowserInfo.IsSafari )
>    eInnerElement.style.height = ( oCell.scrollHeight - 19 ) + 'px' ;
> else
>    eInnerElement.style.height = ( oCell.scrollHeight - 2 ) + 'px' ;
> ```

Comment: Just FYI, the latest update of Chrome seems to have fixed this issue.  So the code above is not necessary.

Answer (score 0):

I see this a lot with Chrome, even on the simplest webpages. Chrome fails to render the bottom 100px or so, showing it as white or showing the contents of another tab. Here's a screenshot that someone posted:
http://i46.tinypic.com/21l061k.jpg

FYI I'm running the very latest version of Chrome so there may be an ongoing issue.